# Compare column and colour the cell if not matched

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns which I am comparing with another two columns. First Column 'B' is checking with Column 'XFD' and if the values are not matching, the cells groundcolour get changed to red. Simultaniously, I am check if column 'C' is matching with column'XFC'.

I want to color the column 'C' if values are not matching but my coding the changing the colour if values are matching. Please advise on coding.

```
Column B  Column C     Column 'XFC    Column 'XFD' 
Q1          Jan-15      Jan-15           Q1
Q2          Oct-15      Feb-15           Q1
Q3          Jul-15      Mar-15           Q1
Q4          Dec-15      Apr-15           Q2
                        May-15           Q2
                        Jun-15           Q2
                        Jul-15           Q3
                        Aug-15           Q3
                        Sep-15           Q3
                        Oct-15           Q4
                        Nov-15           Q4
                        Dec-15           Q4
```

Coding

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim stNow As Date
  Dim lastA As Long
  lastA = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  Dim lastB As Long
  lastB = Range("XFD" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  Dim match As Boolean
  Dim i As Long, j As Long
  Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
  For i = 2 To lastA
   Set r1 = Range("B" & i)
   match = False
   For j = 2 To lastB
      Set r2 = Range("XFD" & j)
      If r1 = r2 Then
         match = True
         If Range("B" & i).Offset(0, 1) = Range("XFD" & j).Offset(0, -1) Then

            Range("B" & i).Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

         End If
      End If
   Next j
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Is there a problem with your code? Do you have a error popping up or is the code just not doing what you expect it to do? If so, what is it doing as opposed to what you wanted it to do? At the same time, I would like to comment that you should code a bit more explicitly: tell VBA what to compare and don't let VBA assume what you want to compare. Hence, I would change `If r1 = r2 then` to `If r1.Value2 = r2.Value2 then` (same for the line `If Range("B" & i).Offet...`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim stNow As Date
Dim lastA As Long
Dim lastB As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim r1 As Range
Dim r2 As Range
Dim i_store As Integer

lastA = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastB = Range("XFD" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastA
   Set r1 = Range("B" & i)
   i_store = 0
   For j = 2 To lastB
      Set r2 = Range("XFD" & j)
      If r1.Value = r2.Value Then
         If Range("B" & i).Offset(0, 1) = Range("XFD" & j).Offset(0, -1)   Then
            i_store = 0
            Exit For
         Else
            If i_store = 0 Then
               i_store = i
            End If
         End If
       End If
   Next j
   If i_store > 0 Then
      Range("B" & i_store).Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
   End If
 Next i
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Just one more favour. Can i also compare the column "B" wiht column "XDF" and highlight the unmatch cell with red